# Python: Convert multiple type of format in string (%, parenthesis, ',') to numeric

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` as following that I would like to convert from string to numeric. Is there any readily available package to do so other than replacing the `',','%'` and bracket with `''` individually?

```
Index Values1    Values2 
a     9,710        19,200
b     41.83%       -21.7%
c     7,857        12,333
d     -7.15%       1.2%
e     (268)        (22)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with escape parentheses by `\` and `regex=True` for substrings replacement:

```
df = df.replace(r'[,%\(\)-]','', regex=True).astype(float)
print (df)
   Values1  Values2
a  9710.00  19200.0
b    41.83    -21.7
c  7857.00  12333.0
d    -7.15      1.2
e   268.00     22.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Also I have value of '-' that I would like to convert to None. I have tried df.replace({'-',None}) but it is not giving the result I after. Do you have any idea how can I do it? Thanks again

Comment: @Teck - add value `-` to `r'[,%\(\)]'`, so finally it is `r'[,%\(\)-]'`